# how to get create id and change its content dynamically with angular

Tags: angular, dom

I have this code and I would like to dynamically create the id and obtain it to be able to change its content by clicking

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of [1, 2, 3]">
    <button  (click)="mycat(row, col)" *ngFor="let col of [1, 2, 3]" class="square">{{enter.zero}}</button>
  </div>
```

and my Ts

```
    public mycat(myrow, mycol){
console.log('hello my friend');
console.log(myrow);
console.log(mycol);
  }
```

if it were with javascript I would use the **DocumentGEtElementByID** or Jquery $("#myid"), but in Angular I don't know

I need that when you click the button, change the content of the button that was clicked, I know that you have to put an id #

Comment: What is enter.zero for? If you're using the same variable as content for all the squares, it'll change everywhere. I suggest you create a 3*3 array for storing the values of each button.

Comment: It can be anything, the only thing I need is to modify what is inside the button

Comment: But that is your content inside every one the squares. If you change one value i.e updating the enter.zero, it'll update everywhere. Anyway if you just need dynamic id for all sqaures, it can be done

Comment: Exactly, how can I get the dynamic identification? I add a id

Comment: See the answer below.

Comment: @migcat Please check my code and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you. You can do that using `document.getElementById` and `HTMLInputElement` content.

To get value using id

```
onClick() {   
     let outputValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('yourID'));
     console.log(outputValue.value);    
  }
```

To set value using id

```
 onClick() {   
       let inputValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('yourID'));
       inputValue.value="SS-Data Set Done";
   }
```

**Note:** Here is a demo code ptovided in the stackblitz.
Please Check the link
[Stackblitz Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enter-focus-by-document-getelementbyid-hgh8ob?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: thank you so much my friend you are great

Comment: @migcat Best of luck. I am glad to hear that your problem is solved. :-)